# Can I still see reports locally if I disable telemetry and crash reportings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I couldn't understand whether I can still see reports locally if I disable them as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_how-to-disable-telemetry-reporting) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_how-to-disable-crash-reporting).

Can I still see reports locally if I disable telemetry and crash reportings?

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: I didn't tried it because of the concern I specified in the question :)

Comment: What reports exactly?  The crash report for VS code itself or your application?

Comment: I mean all of the reports generated by telemetry and crash reportings features of VS code for both of the program itself and for my application

Answer (score 0):

Your first link disables telemetry reporting and the second one disables
crash reporting.

This disables the basic mechanisms, so you will not have the above data if you
disable them.

(In any case, the data is sent to the Microsoft servers and not kept on your computer.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused because I don't disable the features themselves but sending data about reportings to Microsoft. Can you please add your reference(s)?

Comment: My reference is from personal knowledge, but Microsoft doesn't keep a local copy (if enabled or disabled). The only local data you may have is for BSOD is found in `C:\Windows\Minidump` (if not disabled).